# Inclinação de um Guindaste em Opengl

Tags: opengl

Implementei todos os comandos de um guindaste, só faltou a inclinação dele em torno do seu eixo em cima, só que não consigo reproduzir essa inclinação, pois parece que tenho que fazer efeitos de translação e escala ao mesmo tempo para ajustar, porém nao parece ser a melhor forma de fazer isso, olha o problema gerado: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não era para sair do eixo entende?

Código que fiz: http://pastebin.com/JkEQ3un7

```c
 //Base do guindaste é fixa
 glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(2.0, 0.5, 1.0);
    cubo();
 glPopMatrix();

    glRotatef( angGiro, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    {
            //Base cilindrica de cima da base
            // ...
            //Base vertical longa ou Haste vertical
            // ...

            // inclinacao
                    //Parte cilindrica na ponta de cima da base vertical longa
                    // ...
            glRotatef( angInclinacao, 0, 0, 1 );
            {
                    //Cubo horizontal longo ou Viga
                    glPushMatrix();
                            glTranslatef(2-deslViga, 2.75, 0); // deslViga é o deslocamento da viga e diminui metade do que e aumenta/diminui a metade do que o comprimento da viga para poder fazer a relacao de translacao e escala ficarem corretos
                            glScalef( compViga, 0.3, 0.15);
                            cubo();
                    glPopMatrix();

                    //Parte cilindrica na ponta direita da base horizontal
                    glPushMatrix();
                            glTranslatef( compViga, 2.75, -0.0375);
                            glScalef( 0.2, 0.2, 0.075);
                            cilindro();
                    glPopMatrix();

                    //Parte vertical longa e fina no final da parte cilindrica direita
                    // ...
```

Comment: Esqueci de postar o codigo: http://pastebin.com/JkEQ3un7

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português, Jonathas! Quando for fazer uma pergunta, por favor coloque os trechos de código relevantes (quando aplicável) na própria pergunta, ainda que acompanhados de um link para o código completo. Editei sua pergunta com um exemplo de como isso pode ser feito.

Comment: Opa, realmente sou novo, desculpe e obrigado.

Comment: Versão corrigida do problema para quem tiver curiosidade, foi corrigido graças a ajuda do amigo mgibsonbr. http://pastebin.com/QQ6C2MRK, Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você parece estar aplicando a rotação antes da translação para o ponto em torno do qual o giro deve ocorrer. Não tenho experiência com OpenGL, mas notei no seu código que as únicas operações que não estão entre um `glPushMatrix` e um `glPopMatrix` são operações de rotação (`glRotatef`).

Como [essa resposta no gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/16721/12368) indica, embora a ordem usual das transformações é "escala", depois "rotação", depois "translação", quando você quer girar um objeto não em torno do seu próprio centro mas em torno de um outro ponto qualquer, a ordem deve ser "escala", "translação", "rotação" e de novo "translação".

Se você quer que a viga gire em torno de uma de suas extremidades, e não em torno do seu centro, é necessário fazer as operações na ordem citada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De modo que seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim (nota: como já falei, não tenho experiência com OpenGL, guie-se pela imagem acima e não só pelo código abaixo):

```
// inclinacao

        //Parte cilindrica na ponta de cima da base vertical longa
        // ...

glTranslatef(0, 2.75, 0); // Desloca verticalmente da origem até o ponto de rotação
glRotatef( angInclinacao, 0, 0, 1 ); // Após girar
{
        //Cubo horizontal longo ou Viga
        glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(2-deslViga, 0, 0); // Após mover na horizontal
                glScalef( compViga, 0.3, 0.15); // Após aplicar a escala
                cubo();
        glPopMatrix();

        // ...
```

Onde eu coloquei "..." é para continuar fazendo isso, movendo *somente* em relação à origem, e não ao ponto de rotação. Então, onde você faz `glTranslatef( compViga, 2.75, -0.0375)` você vai trocar pra `glTranslatef( compViga, 0, -0.0375)`, `glTranslatef( compViga, 1.75, 0.0 )` troca pra `glTranslatef( compViga, -1, 0.0 )`, etc.

Comment: Cara, você é foda, confesso que jamais esperaria uma resposta tão completa quanto a sua,  nem conhecia o stackoverflow direito, mas pelo visto tenho que frequentar aqui mais,  me ajudou muito a entender o problema, e realmente, o problema de OpenGL e as Matrizes da geometria real é que translocação, rotação e escala ficam de modo reversos, de forma que se no papel voce faria uma rotação primeiro, programando voce faz a  translação primeiro, e vice-versa, muito obrigado pela resposta, abração.

Comment: @JonathasMoreira Sim, as matrizes do OpenGL são "por coluna" (*column major*) enquanto no DirectX elas são "por linha" (*row major*), e as operações com matrizes são pós-multiplicadas (e não pré), de modo que as transformações feitas primeiro no código ocorrerão por último. Tentei reproduzir isso no código da resposta, não sei se consegui. P.S. Se uma resposta resolveu sua dúvida, você tem a opção de marcá-la como "aceita", clicando no ícone ✅ do lado esquerdo da mesma. Se só resolveu parcialmente, você também pode deixá-la em aberto e esperar por respostas alternativas de outros usuários.